# How does the variable length integer work?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction

I'm trying to write a script that constructs a serialized bitcoin transaction from scratch.

But when it comes to the **number of inputs**, the field is a *variable length integer*.

It's typically only 1 byte (2 characters) in length and you do not have to do anything with it, because bitcoin transactions rarely have more than 0xFE (253) inputs.

**But what happens when there are more than 253 inputs and the size of the field has to increase to accommodate it?**

**How would you put a count of 256 inputs in to this field?**

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Variable_length_integer

Answer (score 11):

From the [Bitcoin forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=32849.msg410480#msg410480):

> The way the variable length integer works is:
>
> - Look at the first byte
> - If that first byte is less than 253, use the byte literally
> - If that first byte is 253, read the next two bytes as a little endian 16-bit number (total bytes read = 3)
> - If that first byte is 254, read the next four bytes as a little endian 32-bit number (total bytes read = 5)
> - If that first byte is 255, read the next eight bytes as a little endian 64-bit number (total bytes read = 9)

Answer (score 2):

> How would you put a count of 256 inputs in to this field?

FD 00 01

(00 01) is low-endian representation of decimal(256)

Comment: Thanks. So all values above 0xFD are little-endian? Also, would decimal(65536) be FE 00 00 01?

Comment: no. (FE 00 00 01 00) because FE is prefix for 32-bit low-endian